# Математика и UE5 Blueprints

Tags: vector, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия, unreal-engine-5, unreal-engine

Сложно описать вопрос, но я постараюсь. Есть два пространства(локальное и глобальное), у каждого из них свой вектор направления. Если задать направление вектору а в пространстве альфа(глобальном), то в бета(локальном), он будет иметь другой угол поворота, но по той же оси. Мне нужно чтобы вектор a был одинаковым в обоих пространствах. Возможно есть какие либо формулы для достижения цели? В косинусах и синусах я не очень разбираюсь, да и в математику начал недавно углубляться.
[image: Вектор в двух разных пространствах]

Теперь о том что я хочу сделать в UE5, возможно даст большее понимание:
Есть спавнер, который выбирает рандомную комнату и от этой комнаты - рандомную дверь. Мне нужно чтобы весь актор (как раз таки локальное пространство (relative)) поворачивался в направлении вектора двери комнаты 1, относительно своей выбранной двери.

[image: Комната 1]

Вот что происходит при активации спавнера:

[image: Спавн комнаты 2]

Он выбирает комнату, а потом её дверь, после чего поворачивает и отталкивает на нужный отрезок.

Если есть вопросы, постараюсь ответить. Сам я додуматься не могу который день.

Comment: Если бы можно было менять направление вектора у компонентов или акторов, было бы проще